# TypeError: Cannot read property 'clipboard' of undefined when calling this.$q.electron.clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I am adding copy to clipboard functionality on my app (using Electron).

I use this command:

```
methods: {
   copyToClipboard () {
       if (process.env.MODE === 'electron') {
            this.$q.electron.clipboard.writeText(this.logText)
       }
   }
}
```

But then I get an error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clipboard' of undefined
```

I wonder why. On a separate vue file (main layout vue), I also call `this.$q.electron` functions (minimize, maximize, etc) and they work fine.  The same functions when I try using this component also generates the same error.

I initially used to do this but I need to change implementation since this doesn't work when I build for web (I use web for Cypress testing):

```
const { clipboard } = require('electron')
clipboard.writeText(this.logText)
```

Is `this.$q.electron` only allowed to be used on certain files/levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Fixed this by using the built-in Quasar functoin copyToClipboard() instead.

```
import { copyToClipboard } from 'quasar'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/api/clipboard), the window must be in `non-sandboxed` mode if you want to use `clipboard` in the Renderer process.

So you need to set the sandbox option to `false`.

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      sandbox: false
    }
  })
  win.loadURL('https://google.com')
})
```

See also:
[Electron Sandbox Tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox)